# Nested loops in Knockout.js with if:clause

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am having a problem with nested foreach statements in KO.

The following statements work fine on their own but when I combine them the inner one doesn't work and doesn't throw an error either.

Ideally I would like the inner join to be conditional but I have tried it without the if clause and still no luck.

Experts have a property array of all ExpertRoles assigned to the particular user. The outer loop is meant to print all ExpertRoles and the inner loop is meant to print the Experts that match the Expert role of the outer loop

**1st foreach: WORKS**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: ExpertRoles">
    <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind="attr: { 'data-cid': Id }, text: Name">       
    </li>
</ul>
```

**2nd foreach: WORKS**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Experts">
    <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind="attr: { 'data-cid': ConnectionId, 'title': Username }">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="text: Username"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**combined with if clause: inner loop doesn't work, throws no error**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: ExpertRoles">
    <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind="attr: { 'data-cid': Id }, text: Name">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: Experts">
            <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind="if: ExpertRoles.indexOf($parent.Id) > 0, attr: { 'data-cid': ConnectionId, 'title': Username }">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="text: Username"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**no if clause: inner loop doesn't work, throws no error**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: ExpertRoles">
    <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind="attr: { 'data-cid': Id }, text: Name">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: Experts">
            <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind="attr: { 'data-cid': ConnectionId, 'title': Username }">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="text: Username"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

Let me add that I have tried container-less syntax (`<!-- ko foreach:, <!-- ko if:`, etc)

This is a part of my viewmodel, the data gets updated by SignalR so it is difficult for me to make a fiddle. Please, focus on that **they work on their own**.

```
var viewModel = {
    Users: ko.mapping.fromJS([]),
    ExpertRoles: ko.mapping.fromJS([])
};

// experts are a subset of users
viewModel.Experts = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.Users(), function (item) {
        return item.IsExpert() === true;
    });
}, viewModel);
```

EDIT 2:

With your help I have managed to make the loops work. For some reason binding `Name` on the outer `li` causes the inner loop to stop working.

```
<ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.ExpertRoles -->
        <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind="attr: { 'data-cid': Id }">

            <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            <ul>
                <!-- ko foreach: $root.Experts -->                                    
                    <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind="attr: { 'data-cid': ConnectionId }">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="text: Username"></a>
                    </li>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </ul>

        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Comment: have you tried using container-less if i.e `<!-- if:true -->//markup<!--/ko-->` .

Comment: @supercool - Yes I have, forgot to mention that in my post, let me put it in.

Comment: @Ted how do your models look like?

Comment: @ted can you try making a repro (fiddle sort of) . it will be easy to get your issue fixed .

Comment: i believe you are having issue with binding contexts in your view . do have a second look at those .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `foreach` in a nested loop you can access only properties of a parent model. `Experts` is not a property of an item from the `ExpertRoles`. It is a property of `viewModel` model. That's why it doesn't work. Try using `$root`:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: $root.Experts">
    <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind="if: $root.ExpertRoles.indexOf($parent.Id) >= 0, attr: { 'data-cid': ConnectionId, 'title': Username }">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="text: Username"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have confused you with my naming convention

Comment: Experts have a property array of all ExpertRoles assigned to the particular user. The outer loop is meant to print all ExpertRoles and the inner loop is meant to print the Experts that match the Expert role of the outer loop.

Comment: @Ted `Experts` is a property of the `viewModel`. In your code it is not assigned to a particular user. So you cannot refer to it in your loop for `ExpertRoles`. I've updated my answer. Try `$root`. If you'd like to assign it to a particular user it should be `userModel.Experts = ...` not `viewModel.Experts`.

Comment: Can you forget about the if clause for a moment? I cannot even get the inner loop to display all experts for each expert role. No matter if they match or not, I don't even check that, have a careful read of my entire post, please.

Comment: @Ted I understand that. It is because of the issue I've stated above. Have you tried using `foreach: $root.Experts`?

Comment: @ted try the way @tim mentioned in addition try using `$data` for content inside `foreach` and let us know any console errors .

Comment: I have tried using $root with both Experts and ExpertRoles and still the inner loop doesn't appear. I get no console errors.

Comment: `<ul data-bind="foreach: $root.ExpertRoles">
                    <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind="attr: { 'data-cid': Id }, text: Name">
                        <ul data-bind="foreach: $root.Experts">
                            <li class="expert ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" data-bind=" attr: { 'data-cid': ConnectionId, 'title': Username }">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="text: Username"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>`

Comment: @Ted is the `viewModel` the `root` model or it is inside some other one? Does `Experts` return not an empty array? Also try `$root.Experts()` instead of `$root.Experts`.

Comment: @TimOsadchiy - It's the root model, btw $root & $data make no difference

Comment: i tried building a sample which works perfectly fine here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23468/ . cheers

Comment: @Ted I suggest you building a full example in jsFiddle, which includes your full code and a sample data. I may only guess that `Expers` returns an empty array and the problem might be in `IsExpert()`.

Comment: @supercool - if you add `data-bind="text: $data"` to your outer `li` in your fiddle, you'll see that it stops working. So I'm concluding that you can only loop child elements of arrays and not unrelated arrays like i'm trying to do

Comment: @Ted that's what I've tried to explain you in my answer:)

Comment: @Ted check this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23471/ . only it stops working when nothing is there under parent array(loop) .

Comment: @supercool - for some strange reason, if I `databind Name` to the outer li, the inner loop stops working

Comment: all i can say is debug in diff ways . as ko is super sensitive even a small mistake cause our head banging . see using name will also work fine http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23472/ . nothing strange my friend all we need is to figure out what . .

Comment: @supercool - no it doesn't, add the databind on the li and the inner loop stops working !!! http://jsfiddle.net/q3ft4vsd/

Comment: oooh now i clearly got you intention uff .!! you cannot do that because your `data-bind=text:name` on `li` is replacing `ul` content (it wont even render) . for instance see `<span data-bind="text:name">cool</span.` here name text will replace `cool` . cheers